# Passing UserControl from other Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Calling from within a form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var myControl = new UserControlfrm();
  pnlMain.Controls.Clear();
  pnlMain.Controls.Add(myControl);
}
```

or

```
UserControl myctrl = new UserControlfrm();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 AddPanel(pnlMain);
}

private void AddPanel(Control parent)
{
 parent.Controls.Clear();
 parent.Controls.Add(myctrl);
}
```

How about calling from other class? How correct this

This is the class

```
class MainController
{
 public void AddPanel(Panel pnl, UserControl myctl)
 {
  pnl.Controls.Clear();
  pnl.Controls.Add(myctl);
 }
}
```

This is the main form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 MainController.AddPanel(pnlMain, myctrl);
}
```

where pnlMain is a Panel, and myctrl is a UserControl
I know im missing a point in passing a UserControl. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: you want to reference pass the UserControl to any Class you like?

Comment: yes sir i would like

Comment: any error return?

Comment: Try my solution, if it helps accept it. :)

Comment: what the purpose of your UserControl.. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Add the UserControl to Panel. Which the UserControl is already added in Project. Not as .dll sir

Comment: I just i have to stick to this 'UserControl myctrl = new UserControlfrm();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 AddPanel(pnlMain);
}

private void AddPanel(Control parent)
{
 parent.Controls.Clear();
 parent.Controls.Add(myctrl);
}'

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be:

1. Create a Global Static Class

   ```
   static class Globals
   {
     public static FrameworkElement FE_Global = null;
   }
   ```
2. Then whenever you create an instance of a usercontrol pass it onto this global variable

   ```
   MyUserControl control = new MyUserControl();
   Globals.FE_Global = control;
   ```
3. Now you can access it anywhere in any class

   ```
   MyUserControl cntl = FE_Global as MyUserControl;
   ```

Note: Everytime you create an instance of your control and pass it onto the global variable, the old user control will be replaced by the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call your class like this:

```
MainController.AddPanel(pnlMain, myctrl);
```

Unless you have to change your `class` into `static`:

```
public static void AddPanel(Panel pnl, UserControl myctl)
 {
  pnl.Controls.Clear();
  pnl.Controls.Add(myctl);
 }
```

This is a working example of using a Custom UserControl and Add it to a Form:

Assuming that you have already created your [UserControl Project](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/user-control-in-C-Sharp/).

Form1:

```
UserControl myctrl = new UserControlForm.UserControl1();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainController.AddPanel(panel1, myctrl);
        }
```

Class:

```
class MainController
    {
        public static void AddPanel(Panel pnl, UserControl myctl)
        {
            pnl.Controls.Clear();
            pnl.Controls.Add(myctl);
        }
    }
```

Add to reference `UserControlForm.dll`

Comment: Sir, the UserControl is already added in the Project. Not as .dll sir